# Insert and Select from Updated table simultaneously on the same Button click.(ASP.NET(C#))

Tags: c#, asp.net, insert

I have an `Insert` command which insert values into `myTable` then immediately I want to to select that values from `myTable` which are inserted by the above `insert`.

What should I do to `insert` values and refresh then `select` command should execute on the single `Button` click.

```
  for (int l = 0; l < length; l++)
    {

       // Label1.Text += fid[l];
        FID[l] += Convert.ToInt32(FID1[l]);
       //Label1.Text += FID[l].ToString();

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=ILLUMINATI;" + "Database=DB;Integrated Security= true");
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("Insert into ContentManagement(CreatedBy,ContentTypeId,SubjectName,CreatedDate,FileId,IsArchieved,SessionId,UpdatedBy,LastUpdation,IsDeleted,IsFinalApproved) values(" + memid + ",'" + tpd + "','" + ListBox3.Text + "','" + DateTime.Now + "','" + FID[l] + "','" + z + "','" + session + "','" + memid + "','" + DateTime.Now + "','" + z + "','" + z + "')", conn);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //Label1.Text += "SUCCESS";
        }
        catch
        {
        conn.Close();
        }
        SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection("Server=ILLUMINATI;" + "Database=DB;Integrated Security= true");
        SqlCommand comm1 = new SqlCommand("Select ContentId from ContentManagement where CreatedBy=" + memid + " And ContentTypeId=" + tpd + " And SubjectName='" + ListBox3.Text + "'And FileId=" + FID[l] + "And SessionId=" + session, conn1);

       // try
        //{
            conn1.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr1 = comm1.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr1.Read())
            {
                cntid = Convert.ToInt32(rdr1["ContentId"]);
                Label1.Text += cntid.ToString();
            }
        //}
        //catch
        //{
            conn1.Close();
        //}
        }
```

Comment: And where is problem? Insert and then select. All that you can do in single method :-)

Comment: I have written an insert command then immediately below that tried to retrieve the same record.I'm getting the problem in Select saying record not present.

Comment: Can you **show us** those SQL statements?? Without them, it's a guessing game at best.....

Comment: I edited the question pls check it.

Comment: sorry the question is wrong, sorry for wasting ur time.

Answer (score 1):

You can do using `Stored Procdedure`. In that SP first insert data in table then write select statement.

For ex.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp1] 
 @Param1 VARCHAR(100)            
AS        

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (@Param1)

SELECT * FROM table1
```

Comment: Where should I create this? And how to use this in .cs file?

Comment: IN Your SQL DB create this stored procedure and using DataAdapter you can catch stored procedure output.

Answer (score 1):

Wtite all the queries in the "`Stored Procedures`" and execute the Stored Procedures from button click

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp1] 
 @Param1 VARCHAR(100)            
AS        

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (@Param1)

SELECT top 1 * FROM table1 where memid orderby DESC
```